# javascript location search for multiple query params in url

Tags: javascript, window.location, query-string, pathname

For a url such as

```
http://example.com/x1/x2?qp1a=val1&qp1b=val2#/y1/y2?qp2a=val1b&qp2b=val2b

location.pathname = x1/x2 and location.search = ?qp1a=val1&qp1b=val2
```

how to get `y1/y2` and `?qp2a=val1b&qp2b=val2b` **USING window.location**

Note: I know to solve this using reg ex and other ways, i am more interested in knowing how to get these values using window.location

Comment: Seems like you'll want the split() method of string.

Comment: @ScottMarcus i am looking for window.location helpers mainly thanks.

Comment: I don't see how you are going to get around using split().

Comment: @ScottMarcus thats why the question in stackoverflow : ), you can still use regex, see my comment in the answer section

Comment: split actually uses an implied RegEx as its argument and is usually simpler than explicit RegEx.

Comment: yeah true, still the question was mainly to know if window.location had any particular options. Looks like not, split and regex - yes i know i can use them : ), thanks btw

Answer (score 2):

`location.hash` gets the anchor part of a URL!

In your case it will be #/y1/y2?qp2a=val1b&qp2b=val2b

Then you can remove the leading hashtag using `string.substring()` and split on **?** sign using `string.split()` in order to get the two strings - /y1/y2 and qp2a=val1b&qp2b=val2b

Comment: a simple url.split('#')[1] would provide me the same. 
I am already using a regular expression to match what i want i was just wondering if i could get a window.location which could provide me the pathname and qp better but hash is something that i can use to optimize slightly. thanks

Comment: Happy to help mate. If you come up with better solution, please post here for me and others to learn.

Comment: btw this is what i am currently using.
var hashParts = url.match(/#(\/.+)\?(.+)/i).
hashPath = hashParts[1] and hashSearch = hashParts[2]
http://jsbin.com/modagimipo/edit?html,js,console